# How to stop Maven to mess with my directory layout and its properties?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have `src` directory marked as `source root`. After adding new dependency in `pom.xml` Maven marks `src` as standard/regular directory and then sets `java` directory as `source root` (which is located under src folder: `src/main/java`). It makes all `package` declarations in my classes to become invalid.  How to configure maven to stop doing that?

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to set `src` as a root if you're using the standard `src/main/java`?

Comment: Marked *how*? This sounds like it's not Maven but m2eclipse, and you are manually fiddling with your build settings in Eclipse instead of properly setting everything up in your POM. (And there are very good reasons to use the default Maven layout.)

Comment: Because I already have classes from other project and don't want to rewrite all its package declarations

Comment: @RCola: That doesn't make sense, unless your packages are of the form `main.java.foo.bar` (which would be silly).  If you have package `foo.bar`, you should put it under `src/main/java/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting source directory name explicitly:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

Do not forget to enable autoimport in Idea. You may also need to reimport entire project by opening `pom.xml` file.

Or, as written in comments and IMO the right decision, consider changing your project layout to standard `src/main/java`.